# How to access login user/role in an SQL View

Tags: geoserver, sql

I'd like to filter data in an SQL View based on the logged in user.

For example:

```
SELECT ref_point, project_id, name, username 
FROM   projects 
WHERE  username = '%loginUser%'
```

I know that I can pass whatever value I want in the URL of the request, such as `&viewparams=loginUser:myuser` but I don't want the caller to be able to specify 'any user he wants'. I want my select's `WHERE` clause to ONLY filter based on the real user that is currently logged on.

The goal is to have a single layer that will ONLY show those items in the source table that are tagged to the currently logged in user. In other words, users can ONLY see stuff that belongs to them.

Comment: See e.g. my answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/347246/how-to-limit-a-database-layer-in-qgis-to-the-extent-of-another-layers-feature/347256#347256).

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve what you are looking for by using the session start up/ shutdown script options [as described in the manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlsession.html). For example this alters the current database user to be the same as the GeoServer current user, or geoserver in case no user was authenticated

```
SET SESSION AUTHORIZATION ${GSUSER,geoserver}
```

Comment: I think this is a good hint and is moving me towards a possible solution. I'll be testing this or some variation on this theme. Thank you.